# How to bind collection to chart series itemsource (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, charts

Right now, I have this code:

xaml:

```
 <DVC:Chart Name="MyChart" Background="LightBlue" Margin="10">
            <DVC:Chart.Series>
                <DVC:BarSeries Title="Sumele"
                    IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Key}"
                    DependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Value}">
                </DVC:BarSeries>
            </DVC:Chart.Series>
        </DVC:Chart>
```

xaml.cs:

```
using System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;

     private void LoadBarChartData()
                {
                    ((BarSeries)MyChart.Series[0]).ItemsSource =
                        new KeyValuePair<string, int>[]{
                        new KeyValuePair<string,int>("Project Manager", 12),
                        new KeyValuePair<string,int>("CEO", 25),
                        new KeyValuePair<string,int>("Software Engg.", 5)    
                }
```

Is there a way to bind somehow for example LIST? or DataTable? That will contain all information that I wrote above...

((BarSeries)MyChart.Series[0]).ItemsSource = **(Here)**

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I understood what you want. You could create a Dictionary<String, int> and bind the serie's ItemsSource to it. You could also create a Class that contains the label and the value and make a list of object of this Class

Comment: Thank you for reply, I want to load series dynamically, from List or DataTable ... not by writing each line like (new KeyValuePair<string,int>("Project Manager", 12),)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found solution, how to create that object and insert collection using for loop

```
    int t = 10;
    KeyValuePair<string, int>[] cp = new KeyValuePair<string, int>[t];

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        cp[i] = new KeyValuePair<string, int>("Project Manager", i);
    }
    ((ColumnSeries)MyChart.Series[0]).ItemsSource = cp;
```